# Oracle 11g RDBMS Enterprise Edition download?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am looking for a URL where i can download the Enterprise Edition of Oracle 11g.

I know that i can download the Standard Edition of 11g at Oracle's technet, but as i would like to use some of those enterprise options, which are disabled in standard, i would rather reinstall the enterprise software on our development server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it not [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html) ?

"Oracle Database 11g Release 2
Standard Edition, Standard Edition One, and Enterprise Edition"

Careful of those license costs for dev servers!

Comment: IIRC OTN developer licencing is free - has this changed?

Comment: developer license is still free.

Comment: for a single developer; when he said "our" server sounds like could be more than one user connecting and then Oracle can charge. They can be quite nasty about it too.